# What proportion of detention time is spent by innocent people?

Tags: criminal-law, law-enforcement

The time spent by prisoners in any form of detention is easily found in national statistics. For instance, most EU countries answered the [2022 SPACE I survey](https://www.coe.int/en/web/prison/space). Hence, from [the report](https://wp.unil.ch/space/files/2023/06/230626_SPACE-I_2022_FinalReport.pdf), I can find (p.48, table 8) that on 31 January 2022, there were about 70 000 inmates in France. Assuming there are no significant variations of the prison population with time, that means that a total of 70 000 * 365 = roughly 25 millions man-days are spent in French prisons and jails each year.

I would like to find out what proportion of those days was unjustified, or to put it simply "done by innocents". Define as "innocent" anyone who spent some time in pre-trial detention, but was not ultimately found guilty. I could not find that statistic for France (although any large Western jurisdiction would interest me).

SPACE I has the proportion of population in pre-trial detention vs. sentence, but that alone is insufficient to deduce anything about the guilty-vs-innocent proportion (*). (You could argue that the amount of pre-trial detention is a problem in itself, but let’s assume here that a later sentence retroactively justifies the pre-trial detention.)

Please mention anything that might skew the results, such as:

- someone serving a sentence at the time the dataset was taken (counted as "guilty") might eventually appeal successfully (should be "innocent" by the definition above)
- in countries where a full trial is much more expensive than a guilty plea, many innocent defendants will plead guilty to escape the cost (and risk) of a full trial
- in countries where the judge gives a verdict and a sentence at the same time, a judge faced with a shaky case of a grave crime will sometimes find the defendant guilty but give a low sentence (and such sentences will never be appealed if time was served in pre-trial detention)

---

(*) Consider the following examples:

- in country A, the police and prosecutors are careless but speedy, the judges are harsh but fair. Out of 100 people arrested by the police, all 100 are put in pre-trial detention for a month. After that month, 90 are found to be innocent and let go free, while the 10 others are condemned to 91 months of prison. As a result, the innocents will spend 90×1 = 90 months detained, and the guilty will spend 10×91 = 910 months, split between 10 months of pre-trial detention and 900 months of sentence.
- in country B, the police and prosecutors are very careful, but judges are lenient. Of 100 people arrested by the police, all 100 are put in pre-trial detention for 1 month, after which all 100 are condemned to 10 months of prison (i.e. 9 months left to serve).

In both cases A and B, a total of 1000 months is spent in prison/jail, of which 10% is spent by pre-trial detainees; but for very different reasons. In case B, everyone the police catches is guilty and receives a light sentence; the 10% is just the ratio between the length of pre-trial detention to the total length of sentence. In case A, the pre-trial-to-sentence ratio is much lower (i.e. the guilty are hammered with long sentences and stay very long in prison), which drowns out the fact that most people who ever set foot in jail are innocent (9 out of 10).

Comment: Table 8 also says there were 17527 untried detainees in France, so if you can find the conviction rate...

Comment: To be clear, initially you seem to be asking a question with several components: (1) % detained pretrial who are never convicted and don't die; (2) % of people detained pretrial who are ultimately convicted but are actually innocent; (3) % of people who die in pretrial detention who were innocent (safely ignored as smaller than the uncertainty in the other calculations). But you second paragraph seems to limit the question to category (1) only. So you need the % of inmates who are pretrial detainees, and the % of pretrial detainees not convicted (prob. lower than the total acquittal rate).

Comment: May I suggest a statistic that may help answer this question: I am not sure about the situation in France, but e.g., in Germany, the *StrafEntschädigungsGesetz* (law governing compensation for criminal prosecution) grants 75€ per day of unjustified detainment (that is, both pretrial detainment when the trial does not lead to detainment as well as post-trial detainment when the sentence gets revoked or lowered later). Hence if the total amount of such compensations per year is found somewhere, we can deduce the number of days spent in jail innocently ...

Comment: "Not ultimately found guilty" is of course a very different definition of "innocent" than "did not in fact commit the crime they were accused of".

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen is that an automatic compensation, or at least granted to a large fraction of cases? There is something similar in France but you need to ask for it in court. Given lawyer fees etc., in practice you don’t bother asking if you spent less than six months of unjustified detention. (Also I believe there is no fixed daily rate in France.)

Comment: @ohwilleke The fraction of "actually innocent" is unknowable (at least in a statistical sense for the general population). I did not think about pre-trial deaths (which would usually result in a dismissal of charges), but I suspect they can be neglected. The conviction rate of pretrial detainees can be known, but you also need the pretrial-to-sentence-time ratio (at the extreme: imagine pre-trial detention is on average one minute, and sentences on average twenty years; one sentence equals a million pre-trial detention, hence a lousy conviction rate would be no problem).

Answer (score 1):

### 0.1%

[new-south-wales](/questions/tagged/new-south-wales)

Based on some old data, some back-of-the-envelope calculations, and a whole lot of assumptions.

First the data:

- [Jennifer Galouzis and Simen Corben, 2016, 'Judicial Outcomes of Remand Inmates in New South Wales', Corrective Services NSW](https://correctiveservices.dcj.nsw.gov.au/documents/research-and-statistics/RB034-judicial-outcomes-of-remand-inmates-in-nsw.pdf) is a cohort study of 976 inmates remanded in custody in March 2011 until the completion of their judicial process. Here's assumption number 1; we're going to assume that this cohort is representative of what happens to all remand prisoners in 2023.
- [Australian Bureau of Statistics, 2023, 'Prisoners in Australia'](https://www.abs.gov.au/statistics/people/crime-and-justice/prisoners-australia/latest-release#key-statistics) gives snapshot data at 30 June 2023. There's a lot in here, but we're just going to use the fact that 4,646 of 12,378 (37.5%) of NSW prisoners were unsentanced and that the median time on remand is 3.8 months. With that, and knowing that the median prison time for sentenced prisoners is 3.9 years, we can do some rough-and-ready calculations.

Now these results are only going to be approximate because we're working with medians of two highly skewed data sets - the overwhelming majority of both time on remand and time of sentence are short, but there are outliers of very long times for both. Also, sentenced time probably overstates the time actually served; sentences in NSW are given as a maximum term plus a non-parole period, and most prisoners are released on parole sometime between these.

This figure from the cohort study shows what happened:

[image: Cohort outcomes]

Since you asked specifically about "innocent people", we are only interested in the people who were remanded and then released because their charges were dismissed or they were acquitted. There were 23 out of 589, or 3.9%.

Applying that to the total population, approximately 181 prisoners (1.5% of the total) will ultimately be found "innocent". We'll assume they serve the median amount of time in prison, which is not true because time spent on remand is negatively correlated with findings of "innocence" but we've got to accept that inaccuracy. And we'll also assume that everyone else gets the median sentence (the mean would be better, but we don't have it). So 1.5% serve 3.8 months and 98.5% serve 3.9 years or 46.8 months.

This means that 0.1% of all time served is by people wor are "innocent".

Comment: Good start (+1). Of course it makes hypotheses but nothing too egregious that I can see. (I respectfully suggest to add a summary of the calculation: for every 100 persons found guilty, 1 "innocent" person was on remand; and remand lengths are about 10 times shorter than sentences.)